# Asynchronous call duplicates my ArrayList Entries

Tags: java, gwt, asynchronous, arraylist

I want to send an ArrayList from my server to my client using asynchronous call.
The call succeeds but the ArrayList entries are duplicated during the process.
I am completely lost. The code is very simple. I cant figure out when and where this error takes place.

The shared class:

```
package com.posteurs.cine.shared;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Codes extends ArrayList<Integer> implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//insert 2 values
public Codes(){
    this.add(10);
    this.add(20);
}
}
```

The interfaces:

```
package com.posteurs.cine.client;

import java.util.Set;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;
import com.posteurs.cine.shared.Codes;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("cineSvc")
public interface CineSvc extends RemoteService {
    public Codes getCodes();
}



package com.posteurs.cine.client;

import java.util.Set;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.posteurs.cine.shared.Codes;

public interface CineSvcAsync {
    public void getCodes(AsyncCallback<Codes> callback);
}
```

The implementation:

```
package com.posteurs.cine.server;

import java.util.Iterator;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import com.posteurs.cine.client.CineSvc;
import com.posteurs.cine.shared.Codes;

public class CineSvcImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements CineSvc {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CineSvcImpl(){
    }

    public Codes getCodes(){
        Codes c = new Codes();
        System.out.println("On server -----------------");
        System.out.println("impl.getCodes: Codes size="+c.size());
        return c;
    }
}
```

The call:

```
package com.posteurs.cine.client;

import java.util.Iterator;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.posteurs.cine.client.CineSvcAsync;
import com.posteurs.cine.shared.Codes;

public class Cine implements EntryPoint {
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    CineSvcAsync svc = GWT.create(CineSvc.class);
    svc.getCodes( new AsyncCallback<Codes>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            System.out.println("getCodes::callback: Async failed");
        }

        public void onSuccess(Codes result) {
            System.out.println("On client -----------------");
            System.out.println("Callback result size="+result.size());
            Iterator<Integer> it = result.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) 
                System.out.println(it.next());
        }
        });
}
```

The traced results:

```
    On server -----------------
    impl.getCodes: Codes size=2
    On client -----------------
    Callback result size=4
    10
    20
    10
    20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the duplicate values are caused by their initialization in the default constructor. The default constructor plays a special role in serialization during the "unmarshalling" of the objects. It is called to recreate an "empty" object before copying the serialized field values back to it.

Try initializing the codes somewhere else. For example, you could have a init() method in the Codes class and call this method explicitly in CineSvcImpl.getCodes() after you create the instance.